# What kind of Neural Network learning fits to this scenario? (or maybe other ML should be used?)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

(I am pretty new in ML and ANN)

Unfortunately I can not find the learning method for the following scenario. I am sure this is mainly because I do not know yet some terminology, so my google searches are not as effective as they could be

I have a training set but only inputs. The ideal output for a particular input set can not be determined exactly. (is this called unsupervised?)

However the expectation and learning goal for the NN is pretty clear, but only can determined statistically for many (say all) inputs in the training set, it is one number, and the higher the better.

So say there is an NN with 10 inputs, 4 outputs. I have 100 training sample and want to train the NN to produce the higher Sum1-TO-100(GoalFunc(o1, o2, o3, 4)) which can be computed only for the 100 samples, and does not have meaning for only one sample. (is this called still unsupervised?)

One solution I found out is combining NN and Genetic and implement the NN weights as chromosome. After every epoch evaluate the Sum1TO100 and evolve the population. IF the best chromosome performs good enough then pick it.

Is there any other method to train my NN?

...or...

Is there any other method (not NN) what fits this scenario?

Comment: Unlabelled data generally is used with clustering algorithms. In addition neural nets don't work well with such a small dataset- a rule of thumb is that if you don't have at least 10,000 samples go with an algorithm other than NNs.

Comment: This is a text book example for using a genetic algorithm, not a neural network. Genetic algorithms is a optimization technique, neural networks are used to classify or recognize patterns. Besides your solution of combining both, you could try the pure GA approach.